# pass IDictionary<,> as a parameter in attribute, possible?

Tags: c#, .net

is it possible to pass an IDictionary as an attribute's parameter:
like this:

```
[My(new Dictionary<string,object> { ... }]
```

or like this:

```
[My(Data = new Dictionary<string,object> {...} )]
```

atm I'm thinking to just pass a json string and after transform it into `IDictionary<string,object>`

Comment: Could I also ask why you want to do this?  There could be a better solution than using attributes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No - with attributes you have to pass constant values to them.
Perhaps you could have multiple attributes with two properties exposed.

```
[My(Key = "1234", Value = "1234")]
[My(Key = "4234", Value = "4234")]
```

When you do your reflection, you could build a dictionary that way.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll get this error:

```
Error   20
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```